# Editor Tool, Areas instead of Segments in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, digitizing

I'm studying this tutorial:

https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/get-started-with-arcmap/lessons/predict-the-impact-of-the-proposed-road.htm

But I can't complete the "Digitize the proposed road" section.

When I use the "Trace" and the "Straight Segment" tools, at the end of the drawing I have those "areas" and not just the segments that I would need (you can see the difference looking at picture at point 16 in the previous link):

Is there some option I should be turning off?

[image: What are those areas?]

Comment: Is it possible that you are digitizing into a polygon layer rather into a polyline layer? A snapshot that includes your table of contents, or digitizing tool set will help to provide solution.

Comment: I changed the picture. Now you can see TOC, Editor, Creature Features / Construction Tools panes.

Comment: now it is clear that you are digtizing a polygon, thus the area. Create a new polyline layer and digitize a riad with trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of the tutuorial steps you [created a new feature class](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/get-started-with-arcmap/lessons/predict-the-impact-of-the-proposed-road.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_86683BC370A24AF597A0B1E9C76D826E).  The instructions in the tutorial (step 3) say to create a Line feature class

> Under Type, choose Line Features

however it appears you have created a Polygon feature class.  You can see this in your screenshot where the symbol next to your new layer shows a polygon shape rather than a line shape.

Your new layer showing a Polygon shape symbol:
[image]

Should look something like:
[image]
(from a screenshot further down in the tutorial)

You will need to remove your new layer and redo the Create a new Feature Class steps to create a *line* feature class.

Note the drop-down option set to "Line Features" from the tutorial step 3:
[image]